# Big matrix in two parts

Tags: matrices, tikz-matrix

I'm woriking with a very big matrix in latex (72x72).
I would like to know how can I divide it in two, because I need to write in two different pages.

Thank you for your help. :)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please see https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx for some introductional information.

Comment: For your question: It this big matrix is really necessary and beneficiary to print, then you might consider to divide it in block matrices and print the block matrices individually.

Comment: Is this a matrix of zeros and ones, or something more involved?

Comment: I have a different numbers from 0 to 10000